# Radzyner Ticheiles Dye Process

Tags: tzitzis, techeles

BSD

I am dabbling in research on the topic of the rediscovery of the Ticheiles dye. Of course, one of the historic attempts at a potential Chilazon was discovered by the Radzyner Rebbe (Rav Gershon Henoch Leiner). He identified the Cuttlefish as a potential candidate. For the most part, this theory has been rejected. One reason given for this is that the source of the blueness of the dye is truly a chemical in the dye solution, not the dye itself.

Therefore, in order to complete my analysis of the Radzyner's dye, I need to know precisely what the dye process was. Does anyone know or have any Mekoros for finding out?

Comment: Perhaps one of his three books on _t'cheles_ describes the process? http://hebrewbooks.org/34404 http://hebrewbooks.org/41254 http://hebrewbooks.org/41312

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKhbhTkrGtQ) is pretty good for learning about Radzyn tekhelet, and in it the speaker explains the process.

Comment: Just to make sure you know of [this](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0692890033/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_U_.pEHCbC5CHB08) book on the topic

Comment: Rabbi Herzog wrote his thesis on this in the early 20th century. You can find a link to his thesis here: https://tekhelet.com/pdf/HerzogDoctorate.pdf and some general info on this website:https://www.tekhelet.com/herzogreadingroom/